# Can't read empty input, which should set refresh to 60, gettin error instead

Tags: python

```
refresh = int(input('REFRESH (secs/enter=60s): '))
if refresh == '':   
    refresh = 60
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

When I enter int value Iam not getting error, however I thought this should work when I enter 'nothing'

Comment: `refresh` is the result of a call to `int()`; how could it possibly be an empty string?  You need to do the `int()` *after* checking for empty input.

Comment: Because you are comparing string with integer in refresh == ''"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are mixing your variable types. Instead of converting the text input `refresh` to an `int`, leave it as a string so you can check against an empty string. Then after you have done your checking convert to an `int` (Python does this kind of conversion for you in some cases & other times you have to explcitly do it yourself, I've include both in the code below).

```
refresh = input('REFRESH (secs/enter=60s): ')
print(type(refresh))

if refresh == '':  # here you are comparing a string with an empty string
    refresh = 60   # here Python does the conversion for you
else:
    refresh = int(refresh) # here you explicitly change the string to an int
    
print(refresh)
print(type(refresh))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your first line.

By using `int(var)` you tell the program that var is for sure a valid `int` which it is not.

For positive integers you can use

```py
>>> '16'.isdigit()
True
```